# Подскажите , в Chart.js как выставить графики в один ряд ? (П.С. они все с новой строки идут)

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, диаграммы, chart.js

Подскажите , в Chart.js как выставить графики в один ряд ? (П.С. они все с новой строки идут)

```
     <div  class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:600px; width:600px">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <canvas id="myChart2" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: вот  у вас родитель "chart-container" имеет ширину 600px  а оба потомка в сумме 1000px - как думаете поместятся ли они ?

Comment: та я по разному пробовал ) Это от безысходности

Comment: дайте пример , если есть

Comment: пиши на почту мне  -- надо смотреть исходники ...

Comment: Дайте почту , если можно

Comment: lenovonuj@gmail.com